# How to handle/use path images with css variables? Angular

Tags: css, sass, css-variables

I receive a configuration JSON that has colors and the paths of the images that I must use in my CSS, I correctly set the variables in the html and it would have a result similar to this:

```
    <html lang="en" style="
--c-logo-square:https://linkener-design-tokens.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/localhost/temp%20belike%20small.png;
    --c-background-image:https://linkener-design-tokens.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/localhost/mainBg.png; 
    --c-primary:green; 
    --c-secondary:purple;">
```

I can use the color variables correctly, but I don't know how to use the image paths as background.

```
// Works
.my-html-component {
    color: var(--c-primary);
}

// Error
logo {
  background: url(var(--c-background-image));
}
```

When working with Angular and SCSS I understand that I could use some function that allows me to do what I need, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of defining url in the attribute, define it as a part of the variable. Dont forget to add :root.

```css
:root {
--c-background-image:url(https://linkener-design-tokens.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/localhost/mainBg.png); 
}


.logo {
  background: var(--c-background-image);
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, in the customization JSON I only get the path of the image, what I have done is add the url ('PATH') when reading the field

Comment: Do strings/paths come exactly in this format? '--c-logo-square:https://linkener-design-tokens.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/localhost/temp%20belike%20small.png;'
Can you do a regex on it?

Comment: I guess you already know that it is css variable limitation, that they cannot store urls.  The only thing I see is to parse the JSON strings and replace with regex url

Comment: Accept your answer as valid, thank you. @vega

Comment: I wanted to share this demo I jut made. The value of the CSS attribute is set in the angular component: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3unron?file=src/app/app.component.ts